# Resize GUIDE draw matlab

Tags: matlab-guide

Is possible to change the dimension of my guide without the other things inside move?
I just redisposed objects inside and I want to shrink the dimension of my GUI because is too large with respect the occupied space.

I already tried the same thing to enlarge it, but when I do it all the objects resize as well in a proportional way, while what I want to do is just cut a black part of the window. Is it possible?

Comment: Let me get this straight - do you want to change the figure size? In guide just drag the bottom right corner to make the figure smaller. You might need to control the "[Resize Behavior](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/gui-options.html#f9-998667)" of the figure.

Comment: That's what I meant with "I already tried the same thing to enlarge it, but when I do it all the objects resize as well in a proportional way, while what I want to do is just cut a black part of the window." It changes proportionally also other objects' dimension...I just want to cut one side of the figure

Comment: Could you add a screenshot (or two) showing what you have and what you want to get? It might make the question clearer, at least to me.

Comment: Never mind. I saw that there was selected "Proportional" under Resize Behavior
I don't know why. My fault, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the [Resize Behavior](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/gui-options.html) to something other than "Proportional".